Triviality of induced maps on (reduced) homology implies nullhomotopy?
I'm looking at the following question:

Prove or disprove: a continuous map $f : X \rightarrow Y$ which induces trivial maps $f_*$ in the (reduced) homology with integer coefficients is nullhomotopic.

I have quite poor intuition for these things. I was able to find another post discussing induced maps on the fundamental group, but none on homology. I found a reference online that states without providing details that the regular homology groups are trivial then the map is nullhomotopic.
I have two questions:

Is this true or false? If it's false, what is a counterexample? I could only come up with maps that ended up being nullhomotopic, but I'm still a beginner at AT who struggles to come up with counterexamples.
Geometrically speaking, what is the relationship between these trivial induced maps on homology groups and nullhomotopy of this map? From my (also poor) understanding of homology, trivial homology groups in a sense coincide with "no holes" though it is not immediate to me why this is relevant for arguing why $f$ should be nullhomotopic.

I would be grateful for any guidance or clarification.
Update: The statement is false, as discussed in the responses and in Example 2.38 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book.

Where does your online reference say that explicitly?

@Randall, sorry, I should have included a page reference. It's at the very beginning of page 3: "In particular, f is null-homotopic when the induced homology maps are
trivial."

@Hag: that statement is about maps of chain complexes, not maps of spaces. It's also not true even for chain complexes.

This is false. There exist non-contractible acyclic spaces, that is, spaces whose reduced homology vanishes but which are not contractible. Such a space must have nontrivial $\pi_1$. Wikipedia offers the explicit example of the Poincaré homology sphere minus a point, whose fundamental group is the binary icosahedral group.
If $X$ is such a space, the identity map $f : X \to X$ induces zero on reduced homology but is not null-homotopic (because it doesn't induce zero on $\pi_1$).
The corresponding statement about chain complexes claimed in the notes you linked is also false. I am guessing the author meant to say the opposite, namely that a null-homotopic chain map induces the zero map on homology. The details are probably not so relevant to you but here they are if you want them:

Let $A$ be an abelian category with enough projectives (such as modules), let $X, Y \in A$ be two objects such that $\text{Ext}^n(X, Y) \neq 0$ for some $n \ge 1$, and let $\widetilde{X}$ be a projective resolution of $X$ in $\text{Ch}(A)$. Then the only nonzero homology of $\widetilde{X}$ is $H_0(\widetilde{X}) \cong X$, and if we consider the complex $Y[n]$ which is given by $Y$ in degree $n$ then the only nonzero homology of $Y[n]$ is $H_n(Y[n]) \cong Y$. But homotopy classes of chain maps $\widetilde{X} \to Y[n]$ are in natural bijection with $\text{Ext}^n(X, Y)$, so by hypothesis there is some such map which is not null-homotopic even though it necessarily induces the zero map on homology. To be explicit we can take $A = \text{Ab}$, $X = Y = \mathbb{Z}/p$ for $p$ a prime, $n = 1$, and the free resolution of $X$ given by $\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{Z}$.

There are also standard examples showing that a map (between path-connected spaces) which induces zero on all homotopy groups need not be null-homotopic. You can take $X = BG, Y = B^2 A$ to be two Eilenberg-MacLane spaces; homotopy classes of maps $f : BG \to B^2 A$ are in natural bijection with group cohomology $H^2(G, A)$ and classify central extensions $A \to H \to G$. There is also a geometrically simpler example $X = T^2, Y = S^2$, where there are countably many homotopy classes of maps $f : X \to Y$ classified by degree.
I think it is still not true even if you ask for a map to induce zero on reduced homology and homotopy groups but this condition blocks the easy counterexamples.

I'm glad that you still do maintain your "voice" here. Your poignant disclaimer about your grad-school posts was good, too, and/but, ok, "you're good".

@paul: thank you! I'm glad to be here too.

Thank you so much for the detailed response! It was very insightful. I realized not long after posting this question that this is also discussed in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book (Example 2.38 if anybody else who comes across this post wondering the same thing) but completely forgot to update the post.
